# "JSR-303 Provider is on the classpath" Means

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3. Here is the my model,

```
public class MarketPlace {

    @NotNull(message="This Template Name is required")
    @Size(max=50)
    private String templateName;

    public String getTemplateName() {
        return templateName;
    }

    public void setTemplateName(String templateName) {
        this.templateName = templateName;
    }

}
```

and here is the controller method,

```
public String PublishForm(@Valid MarketPlace m, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "Error";
    }
    return "Sucess";
}
```

But hasErrors is always false.
Then I put these lines in dispather-servelet,

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
................

mvc:annotation-driven /
```

But now now, NetBean showing me this error,

```
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven.
```

Some people suggests me to
"Set JSR-303 Provider is on the classpath"

What does this means.
I have these jars in my application,

```
lib\slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar, 
build/web/Resources/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar, 
build/web/Resources/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
```

Edit:

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="demo.htm">DemoAppMarketController 
.................................
  <bean name="indexController"
          class="Controller.IndexControler"

Answer (score 2):

You have to be sure that the following `xsi:schemaLocation` entries exist:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
```

In addition look at this tutorial it explains how to work JSR-303 Providers.

http://www.openscope.net/2010/02/08/spring-mvc-3-0-and-jsr-303-aka-javax-validation/

**Update:**
Frankly, I prefer another way for URL mapping: 
all jsp requested are mapped to *.html URLS.

Now your Dispatcher servlet looks like that:

```
 <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Than your Spring URL mapping looks like that:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, after putting this all of my application breaks and throwing this error, 

"javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler". 

Note, this is old application and url are mapped as, See above

Comment: But I will not able to this huge application. I need a quick way to add validation in my application just like ASP.NET MVC doing since it's version 2.